# Solidity Ethereum Multi-Signature Vault Contract

Tags: solidity

This is a smart contract that I wrote in Solidity which is intended to store Ethereum securely. I intended it to be simple, mostly because I wanted it to be inexpensive to deploy and gas efficient. I decided to write it because I could not find an existing solution that was not very expensive to deploy, and I wanted to see if I could write one. I'd say that i was moderately successful at that -- I had hoped to keep deploy costs to 1,000,000 gas max, and they ended up being about 1,400,000 gas to deploy.

Anyway, the logic works like this: The user deploys the contract and supplies as parameters an array of authorized signer accounts (ethereum addresses), a daily spending allowance (withdrawal requests under this limit do not require multisig approval), and a threshold (which is how many signers are required before a transaction requiring approval executes). The spending limit is simply an ethereum value, I did not implement any price oracle functionality. For that reason, I realized it was important to be able to later change those initial values, and thus the only other functions that the contract has are for updating those three parameters. In order for any of those values to be update, all of the currently active signers must approve. I realize that may seem counter-intuitive to some people (ie., requiring the signature of an account you are trying to revoke), but for my use case, it makes sense.

I am looking for any feedback as to how I could improve this contract. Specifically, I am curious as to whether or not this is actually even secure, and also if anyone knows how I could further reduce the deployment costs, I'd be very interested to hear your idea. Without further ado, here is the code.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.16;
// SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT
/*

888~~    d8   888                       Y88b      /                    888   d8
888___ _d88__ 888-~88e  e88~~8e  888-~\  Y88b    /    /~~~8e  888  888 888 _d88__
888     888   888  888 d888  88b 888      Y88b  /         88b 888  888 888  888
888     888   888  888 8888__888 888       Y888/     e88~-888 888  888 888  888
888     888   888  888 Y888    , 888        Y8/     C888  888 888  888 888  888
888___  "88_/ 888  888  "88___/  888         Y       "88_-888 "88_-888 888  "88_/

Darkerego, 2023 ~ Ethervault is a lightweight, gas effecient,
multisignature wallet

*/
contract EtherVault {

    /*
      @dev: gas optimized variable packing
    */
    uint8 private debugMode;
    uint8 private mutex;
    uint8 public signerCount;
    uint8 public threshold;
    uint16 public proposalId;
    uint32 public execNonce;
    uint32 private txCount;
    uint32 private lastDay;
    uint128 public dailyLimit;
    uint128 public spentToday;


    struct Proposal{
        address proposer;
        address modifiedSigner;
        uint8 newThreshold;
        uint8 numSigners;
        uint32 initiated;
        uint128 newLimit;
        mapping (address => uint8) approvals;
    }

    struct Transaction{
        address dest;
        uint128 value;
        bytes data;
        uint8 numSigners;
        mapping (address => uint8) approvals;
    }

    /*
      @dev: Error codes:
      This is cheaper than using require statements or strings.
      Tried using bytes, but no good way to convert them to strings,
      so that leaves unsigned ints as error codes.
    */
    bytes2 aErr = "03";
    bytes2 pErr = "12";
    bytes2 tErr = "05";
    bytes2 nErr = "06";
    error FailAndRevert(bytes2);

    /*
      @dev: Error Codes are loosely modeled after HTTP error codes. Their definitions are
      here and in the documentation:

      03 -- Restricted Function Errors
          -- Access denied for caller attempting to access protected function (caller is not a signer)
          -- Access denied because state is Locked (blocked attempted reentrancy)
      04 -- Transaction Errors
          -- Cannot execute because transaction not found (either already executed or invalid txid)
          -- Insufficient balance for request
      06 -- Nonce Error
      12 Signature Errors
         -- Cannot add signer because address already is a signer
         -- Cannot sign, no proposal Found
         -- Cannot revoke because address is not a signer
         -- Cannot sign because caller already signed
         -- Cannot propose, proposal already pending

    */


    /*
      @dev: Mapping Indexes
       Signer address => 1 (substituted for bool to save gas)
       TXID > Transaction
       ProposalID => Proposal
    */
    mapping (address => uint8) isSigner;
    mapping (uint32 => Transaction) public pendingTxs;
    mapping (uint16 => Proposal) public pendingProposals;

    function auth(address s, uint32 _nonce) private {
        /*
          @dev: Checks if sender is a signer, checks nonce,
          and ensures system state is not locked.
        */
        if( isSigner[s] == 0 ||_nonce <= execNonce|| mutex == 1){
            revert FailAndRevert(aErr);
       } // increment nonce if all checks pass
       execNonce += 1;
    }


    modifier protected(uint32 _nonce) {
        /*
          @dev: Restricted function access protection and reentrancy guards.
          Saves some gas by combining these checks and using an int instead of
          bool.
        */
       auth(msg.sender, _nonce);
       mutex = 1;
       _;
       mutex = 0;

    }

    constructor(
        address[] memory _signers,
        uint8 _threshold,
        uint128 _dailyLimit
        ){
            /*
              @dev: When I wrote this, I never imagined having more than 128
              signers. If for some reason you do, you may want to modify this code.
            */

        unchecked{ // save some gas
        uint8 slen = uint8(_signers.length);
        signerCount = slen;
        for (uint8 i = 0; i < slen; i++) {
            isSigner[_signers[i]] = 1;
        }
      }
        (threshold, dailyLimit, spentToday, mutex, debugMode) = (_threshold, _dailyLimit, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    function alreadySigned(
        /*
          @dev: Checks to make sure that signer cannot sign multiple times.
        */
        uint32 txid,
        address owner
    ) private view returns(bool){
        if (pendingTxs[txid].approvals[owner] == 0){
           return false;
       }
       return true;
    }

    function alreadySignedProposal(address signer) private view {
        if (pendingProposals[proposalId].approvals[signer] == 1){
            revert FailAndRevert(pErr);
        }
    }

    function execute(
        /*
            @dev: Function to execute a transaction with arbitrary parameters. Handles
            all withdrawals, etc. Can be used for token transfers, eth transfers,
            or anything else.
        */
        address r,
        uint256 v,
        bytes memory d
        ) private {
       /*
         @dev: Gas efficient arbitrary call in assembly.
       */
        assembly {
            let success_ := call(gas(), r, v, add(d, 0x00), mload(d), 0x20, 0x0)
            let success := eq(success_, 0x1)
            if iszero(success) {
                revert(mload(d), add(d, 0x20))
            }
        }
    }

    function signProposal(address caller, uint16 _proposalId) private {
        /*
          @dev: Function marks signer (the caller) as having confirmed the given proposal id.
        */
        pendingProposals[_proposalId].approvals[caller] = 1;
        pendingProposals[_proposalId].numSigners += 1;
    }

    function newProposal(
        /*
          @dev: Create a new proposal to change the daily limits, the signer threshold, or to
          add or revoke a signer. If the specified address is already a signer, then this is a
          revokation change. If not, it is a granting change.
        */
        address _signer,
        uint128 _limit,
        uint8 _threshold,
        uint32 _nonce
    ) external protected(_nonce) returns(uint16){
        proposalId += 1;
        Proposal storage prop = pendingProposals[proposalId];
        (prop.modifiedSigner, prop.newLimit, prop.initiated,
        prop.newThreshold, prop.proposer) = (_signer, _limit,
        uint32(block.timestamp),  _threshold, msg.sender);
        signProposal(msg.sender, proposalId);
        return proposalId;
    }

    function deleteProposal(uint16 _proposalId, uint32 _nonce) external protected(_nonce) {
        /*
          @dev: Allow only the proposer to delete a pending proposal they created.
        */
        Proposal storage proposalObj = pendingProposals[_proposalId];
        if (proposalObj.proposer == msg.sender){
            delete pendingProposals[_proposalId];
        }
    }


    function approveProposal(uint16 _proposalId,  uint32 _nonce) external protected(_nonce) {
        /*
          @dev: Approve a pending proposal.
        */
        alreadySignedProposal(msg.sender);
        Proposal storage proposalObj = pendingProposals[_proposalId];

        // if all signers have signed
        if(proposalObj.numSigners +1 == signerCount)  {
             // if limit/threshold are being updated
            if (proposalObj.newLimit > 0||proposalObj.newThreshold >0){

                dailyLimit = proposalObj.newLimit;
                threshold = proposalObj.newThreshold;
            }
            // if updating signers
            if (proposalObj.modifiedSigner != address(0)) {
                if (isSigner[proposalObj.modifiedSigner] == 1) {
                    /*
                    @dev: Signer exists, so this must be a revokation proposal.
                    revoke this signer and reset the approval count.
                    Admin cannot be revoked.
                    */
                    isSigner[proposalObj.modifiedSigner] = 0;
                    signerCount-=1;

                } else {
                    /*
                    @dev: Signer does not exist yet, so this must be signer addition.
                    Grant signer role, reset pending signer count.
                    */
                    isSigner[proposalObj.modifiedSigner] = 1;
                    signerCount+=1;
            }
            }
            if (debugMode == 0) {
                // delete unless debug mode is on
                delete pendingProposals[_proposalId];
            }
        } else {
            // More signatures needed, so just sign.
            signProposal(msg.sender, _proposalId);
        }
    }





    function deleteTx(
        /*
          @dev: Remove pending transaction from storage and cancel it.
        */
        uint32 txid,
        uint32 _nonce
        ) external protected(_nonce) {

        if (pendingTxs[txid].dest == address(0)) {
            revert FailAndRevert(tErr);
        }
        delete pendingTxs[txid];
    }


    function approveTx(
        /*
          @dev: Function to approve a pending tx. If the signature threshold
          is met, the transaction will be executed in this same call. Reverts
          if the caller is the same signer that initialized or already approved
          the transaction.
        */
        uint32 txid,
        uint32 _nonce
        ) external protected(_nonce) {
        Transaction storage _tx = pendingTxs[txid];
        if(!alreadySigned(txid, msg.sender)){
            if (_tx.dest == address(0)){
                revert FailAndRevert(tErr); // tx does not exist
            }
            if(_tx.numSigners + 1 >= threshold){
                execute(_tx.dest, _tx.value, _tx.data);
                delete pendingTxs[txid];
            } else {
                signTx(txid, msg.sender);
            }

        } else {
            revert FailAndRevert(tErr);
        }
    }

    function signTx(uint32 txid, address signer) private {
        /*
          @dev: register a transaction confirmation.
        */
        pendingTxs[txid].approvals[signer] = 1;
        pendingTxs[txid].numSigners += 1;
    }

    function submitTx(
        /*
          @dev: Initiate a new transaction. Logic flow:
          (Note: to save gas, the nonce also doubles as the TXID.)
           1) First, check the "nonce"
           2) Next, check that we have balance to cover this transaction.
           3) Check if requested ethere value (in wei) is below our daily
           allowance:
             yes) The transaction will be executed here and value added to `spentToday`.
             no)  The transaction requires the approval of `threshold` signatories,
                  so it will be queued pending approval.
        */
        address recipient,
        uint128 value,
        bytes memory data,
        uint32 _nonce

        ) external payable protected(_nonce) returns(uint32) {

        // gas effecient balance call
        uint128 self;
        assembly {
            self :=selfbalance()
        }
        // make sure we have equity for this request
        if(self < value){
            revert FailAndRevert(tErr);
        }

        if (underLimit(value)) {
            // limit not reached, no further authorization required.
            spentToday += value;
            execute(recipient, value, data);
        } else {
            txCount += 1;
            // requires approval from signatories -- not factored into daily allowance
            Transaction storage txObject = pendingTxs[txCount];
            (txObject.dest, txObject.value, txObject.data) = (recipient, value, data);
            signTx(txCount, msg.sender);
        }
        return txCount;

    }

    function underLimit(uint128 _value) private returns (bool) {
        /*
          @dev: Function to determine whether or not a requested
          transaction's value is over the daily allowance and
          shall require additional confirmation or not. If it is
          a different day from the last time this ran, reset the
          allowance.
        */
        uint32 t = uint32(block.timestamp / 1 days);
        if (t > lastDay) {
            spentToday = 0;
            lastDay = t;
        }
        // check to see if there's enough left
        if (spentToday + _value <= dailyLimit) {
            return true;
        }
            return false;
    }

     /*
       @dev: Allow arbitrary deposits to contract.
     */

     receive() external payable {}

}
```

Comment: If you are a legal entity / natural person dba Darkerego, and you want copyright protection for this MIT-licensed work, then instead of "Darkerego, 2023" you should explicitly write "Darkerego, Copyright 2023". Single character names won't help you and your collaborators if you strive for bug-free code. And the {a,p,t,n}Err identifiers are no improvement. A description of how 1.4 M gas is spent during some typical expected transactions would be helpful, since "low spend" is apparently one of the design goals that affects how we evaluate "correctness" here.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! Ya you are right, those error names are really non descriptive! Also, good to know about the copyright. BTW, the 1,400,000 gas I was strictly talking about deployment costs.